# How to stop the phone's adress book asking for synchronization with Messenger contacts?

Tags: samsung, calls, facebook-messenger

I am using a Galaxy A41, Android version 10 maybe (honestly i can't make sense of the version indications in the Software information tab.)

Recently when i go to Phone -> Contacts (or Address book, i'm not sure of the translation) ; the phone will randomly display a popup asking me if i want to synchronize my phone contacts with my Messenger (im guessing facebook messenger) contacts. I don't want to do that ever, and i don't want to be asked for that. 
Is there any way I can stop that popup from ever showing up ? I tend to use my contact list a lot, and it's becoming annoying to have that invasive and unwelcomed functionality trying to force itself upon me each time I want to make a call. I already tried to got to Settings -> Accounts -> uncheck Automatically synchronise datas (i don't use that at all apparently). 
Thanks !

edit : Here is a screen capture of the popup - name of phone contacts are blurred for privacy concerns. The popup reads :

> " Activate Automatic synchronization ? To synchronize your
> contacts and keep them up-to-date on all your devices, activate
> Automatic synchronization for Messenger.  Cancel | Activate"

[image]

Comment: Could you please make a screen shot and include it in your question even if it doesn't show the question in English? Because that apps ask for sync permission is common but that the contacts app asks is a bit unusual...

Comment: edited original question to inlcude a screen capture of the popup.

Comment: Looks like [this is the same issue with the error message in the original English text](https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Samsung-Apps-and-Services/Nag-popup-to-sync-contacts-with-messenger/td-p/1555923). You may try the solutions provided on there, then feel free to [post a working solution on here](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) while also [providing a proper attribution](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) :)

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the exact same problem as the one you linked to. However, there is no solution provided there afaict ; only indication on how to effectively turn on or off the sync manually. I tried to do that but there is no option to opt-out for the automatic reminder in those options.